# HTML Anchor tag stops working when className is changed in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to intercept a click on an  tag to change the CSS class when it is selected and then I would like the process to continue to the href specified in the  statement.  I have created a javascript function which changes the classes for the three links of interest but for some reason, the links do not perform their default action of jumping to the address specified in href.  The class values change as expected.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

The HTML (part of a cshtml view):

```
ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active nav-data-tab" onclick="setActiveTab(1)" id="NI-ColonyData" data-toggle="tab" href="#ColonyData"><h4>Colony Data</h4></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" onclick="setActiveTab(2)" id="NI-Weather" data-toggle="tab" href="#Weather"><h4>Weather</h4></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" onclick="setActiveTab(3)" id="NI-Actions" data-toggle="tab" href="#Actions"><h4>Actions</h4></a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item" hidden>
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#Pesticide">Pesticide</a>
</li>
```

Javascript here:

```
function setActiveTab(tabNum) {
    var CD = document.getElementById('NI-ColonyData');
    var W = document.getElementById("NI-Weather");
    var A = document.getElementById("NI-Actions");

    if (tabNum == 1) {
        CD.className = "nav-link active nav-data-tab";
        W.className = "nav-link";
        A.className = "nav-link";

    }
    else if (tabNum == 2) {
        CD.className = "nav-link";
        W.className = "nav-link active nav-data-tab";
        A.className = "nav-link";
    }
    else if (tabNum == 3) {
        CD.className = "nav-link";
        W.className = "nav-link";
        A.className = "nav-link active nav-data-tab";
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `className =` Use the proper [classList methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) instead. Doing `className` you'll erase all previous classes designated to an element. Don't repeat yourself. Learn how to use the [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: For your specific task (Anchor targets `#`) you don't need any JavaScript. Only the `:target` selector in CSS. `data-toggle="tab"` seems not like the proper use of data-*. In JS I would expect to have a selector like: `data-toggle="#Weather"` but, as I said, useless since you already use anchor targets.

Comment: it seems to work correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/7oux40rk/ Could you please clarify this: "but for some reason, the links do not perform their default action of jumping to the address specified in href"

Comment: When I use onclick to run the setActiveTab function, the link does not appear to do anything - does not take you to the anchor specified in the href attribute.

Comment: I edited the fiddle, hash href is working correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/hze4bkj1/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses.  Appreciate GrafiCode showing the simple stand-alone code worked.  I believe the issue was a conflict with bootstrap so I changed my approach to eliminate the js and just add some local css which is selected using the same selectors as in bootstrap when the tab is pressed.